# How to find rectangular matrix $A$ such that $A*B $is positive definite for a given rectangular matrix $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite

Given B, A rectangular $m \times n$ matrix.

I would want to find a rectangular matrix; $A_{m \times n }$   such that $AB$ is positive/negative definite.

there exists No further assumptions on the matrix $B$.

Comment: could you show us your effort?

Comment: I first tried u^TABu as u^TAu^TuBu/u^Tu. but since the matrices are rectangular, we can't go further by examining u^TAu for positiveness. Now, I am working on expressing u^TABu by rows of A and columns of B.

Comment: Don't you impose $AB$ to be as well _symmetric_ because positive-definiteness is usually defined for symmetric matrices ?

Comment: There's a well known standard $A$ such that $(ABx)\cdot x=(Bx)\cdot Bx=||Bx||^2$